# Raspberry Pi web server that controls hardware

Tags: python, web-services, raspberry-pi3

First, thank you all for your useful posts. I can usually find what I need from SE without needing to make a post.

I'm hoping to make a timer/sensor device that I can control from a web browser.

I'm planning to hook up a set of sensors by USB or pinouts to a Raspberry pi, then having the Pi host a web server. I have experience writing web servers from scratch in python, so I intend to use python as my programming language for this application as well.

I want to be able to visit the server from another device that will run at a time-keeper's station. By selecting options on the web site, you could control the display portion of the timer or the values of variables (timer reset) also the sensors could trigger update events to show information on the web page.

My primary obstacle in this case is the hardware interface. I imagine I would need to look up how sites like OMSI allow users to control the motors that move their webcam, or other online control of hardware.

What should my search terms be, or do you know of any libraries for python to read and write to external (adafruit-style) sensors?

Thanks!

Anthony
(https://i.stack.imgur./RzWIl.png)

Comment: I believe I'm asking for code related vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

"Raspberry pi python gpio" "Raspberry pi python i2c" "Raspberry pi python spi"